# Adfs authenticate on dotnet core aspboilerplate

Tags: .net-core, adfs, aspnetboilerplate

I am developing a web app with boilerplate "dotnet core" version. I want to authenticate user with adfs. I've searched on Google and the Boilerplate forum. But I didnt find any detailed info. I am newbie to abp.

Comment: the documentation would be a better place to start.  read the part on external auth: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/User-Management?searchKey=adfs

Comment: https://forum.aspnetboilerplate.com/viewtopic.php?p=2322#p2322

Comment: @JohnB I looked at this page. but the "external auth source" mentioned on this page is available directly to "adq authenticate".  am i wrong ?

Comment: @AlperEbicoglu i am looking for adfs, not ad or ldap :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very nice explanations and sample project using dot net core with Azure ad integration using open connect.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

You might also be interested in this sample: https://github.com/azure-samples/ms-identity-aspnetcore-webapp-tutorial/

This newer sample takes advantage of the Microsoft identity platform (formerly Azure AD v2.0).

While still in public preview, every component is supported in production environments.

This sample shows how to build a .NET MVC web app that uses OpenID Connect to sign-in users from a single Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant using the ASP.NET Core OpenID Connect middleware.

For a quick start you can use below command

git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore.git

Flow

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have to use adfs. The customer don't accept in another way.

Comment: how about this : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/ws-federation.md